# Bootstrap tab persistance on page reload, but not how to do it

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I've read several posts on how to make a tab in bootstrap maintain its state after a page reload. I came up with a totally different way that is specific to my situation, so I'm not asking how you do it.

At the end of my page I have just this code, and I'm using TWIG templates to inject the vales as necessary. It case you don't know, that is what the {{ tab_index }} part is all about. I'm simply injecting the index number of the tab I want open when the page loads.

Anyway, this little snippet is at the end of my page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.nav-tabs li:eq({{ tab_index }}) a').tab('show');
});
```

Simple enough, except when the page initially loads it's on the first tab then quickly changes to the tab I tell it to show. That creates a "flicker" that looks pretty stupid. Is there a way to maybe switch to the tab without the flicker? Maybe switch to the appropriate tab when the page is loaded, but before it is displayed?

EDIT:
Ok here is some code to show you how it works:

First off I'm using an MVC structure and Twig templates as my view. So, in my router table I defined a route like [Controller]/[id]/[Action]. The id can be any integer. So the router parses the Controller, id and action as different values in an array. The Controller value is the name of the class to instantiate and the Action is the method to call in that new controller object. The id can be any integer for any reason and can be accessed from the array that the router creates.

Now, each tab on my page will be a different form. So, the idea is that in the action of each form the URL will be like [Controller]/[id]/[Action]. Right now I have two forms that look like this:

```
<form name="personal_form" id="personal_form" method="post" action="{{ domain }}/members/profile/0/personal" class="form" role="form">
```

and

```
<form name="password_form" id="password_form" method="post" action="{{ domain }}/members/profile/1/password" class="form" role="form">
```

The {{ domain }} part is just so I can inject the domain of my site into the Twig template and use absolute URL's. The magic is in that number in the URL.

When you click the submit button, lets say on the password_form, which would be the second tab (tab index 1), the router creates a rout_param[] array with controller => profile, id => 1, action => password.

Then in my PHP script, which is the target of the form action, if route_param['id'] is set, it defines the tab_index property of the object to that id number.

```
if (isset($this->route_params['id'])) {
   $this->tab_index = $this->route_params['id'];
}
```

The default value of tab_index is 0, so if no id is in the array, the tab_index will remain 0.

After I have that I render my Twig template:

```
View::renderTemplate('Members/profile.twig', ['member' => $this->member,
                              'domain' => Config::DOMAIN,
                              'tab_index' => $this->tab_index]);
```

The important part is you see I'm passing the tab_index number to the template as tab_index.

Finally in the template I am using JQuery to show the open tab based on its index number:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.nav-tabs li:eq({{ tab_index }}) a').tab('show');
});
```

That then tells the bootstrap tab to show the appropriate tab.

The problem is, that appropriate tab is not initially the open tab. The first tab opens when the page is loaded then it switches to the appropriate tab. That causes a flicker as it switches from one tab to the other.

Can that be avoided? Sorry, I know that was a lot of words to say a little.

Comment: is it possible for you to share the html and may be the jsfiddle of your problem. Fixing it right there would be easier..

Comment: Sure give me a minute, but it may take some explaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops I'm an idiot! To use the bootstrap tabs, you set the content area of the default tab to active and well as the default tab itself. Then when you open the web page, that tab and content are open on page load.

So, in my case, the default opened on page load, then switched to the one I told it to open. You could see the page switch when the page loaded, which is not what I wanted.

I simply took the active class off the tab and the content associated with that tab. The affect was that there was no default page already open when the page loaded. Hence no tab switch from the default to the one I wanted. It just opens to the one I want from the get go.